# Specifying default value for component prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a re-usable form component that given a schema submits a set of fields to a backend service. I want to extend it such that I can pass in an optional React component to denote that the form submission was successful. If no component is specified, I want it to render the default.

```
import DefaultFormSuccess from './default-form-success';

...

const GenericFormHelper = formProps => {
  const {
    form,
    posting,
    postingSuccess,
    successComponent = DefaultFormSuccess,
    ..restFormProps
  } = formProps;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form {...restFormProps}
        <fieldset>
         // Fields go here
        <fieldset>
      </form>
     {postingSuccess && successComponent}
    </div>
  );
```

I have a generic default component which looks like this :-

```
const DefaultFormSuccess = () => {
  return (
    <p>Form Submission Successful!</p>
  );

export default DefaultFormSuccess;
```

If I define a custom success component like this

```
const CustomSuccess = () => {
  return (
    <p>Thanks! We'll get back to you within 24 hours</p>
  );
```

and call my form passing in my custom success component it works

```
  <GenericFormHelper successComponent={<CustomSuccess />} />
```

but just calling

```
<GenericFormHelper />
```

results in a console error `functions are not valid as a React child`

modifying the line

```
postingFailure && failureComponent
```

to

```
postingFailure && failureComponent()
```

works when no component is passed in but fails when I do pass the component in with `failureComponent is not a function`.

So my question is, how can I get it to work for both scenarios?

Comment: Did you try `successComponent = <DefaultFormSuccess />`, instead of `successComponent = DefaultFormSuccess`?

Comment: I did something in [code pen](https://codepen.io/ms314006/pen/qBboYgO), maybe that is you want, if I had mistake please tell me. :)

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-moore-56ugo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Clark That worked! `successComponent = <DefaultFormSuccess />` did the trick. Can't believe I missed that. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `successComponent = <DefaultFormSuccess />`, instead of `successComponent = DefaultFormSuccess`? Like below snippet:

```js
const GenericFormHelper = formProps => {
  const {
    form,
    posting,
    postingSuccess,
    successComponent = <DefaultFormSuccess />,
    ..restFormProps
  } = formProps;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form {...restFormProps}
        <fieldset>
         // Fields go here
        <fieldset>
      </form>
     {postingSuccess && successComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I did something in [code pen](https://codepen.io/ms314006/pen/qBboYgO), maybe that is you want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
{postingSuccess && typeof successComponent === 'function' ? successComponent() : successComponent}
```

Comment: Explaine what you write please.